# Scala map with dependent variables

Tags: scala, apache-spark, foldleft

In scala I have a list of functions that return a value. The order in which the functions are executed are important since the argument of function `n` is the output of function `n-1`.

This hints to use `foldLeft`, something like:

```
val base: A
val funcs: Seq[Function[A, A]]

funcs.foldLeft(base)(x, f) => f(x)
```

(detail: type `A` is actually a Spark DataFrame).

However, the results of each functions are mutually exclusive and in the end I want the union of all the results for each function.
This hints to use a `map`, something like:

```
funcs.map(f => f(base)).reduce(_.union(_)
```

But here each function is applied to `base` which is not what I want.

Short: A list of variable length of ordered functions needs to return a list of equal length of return values, where each value `n-1` was the input for function `n` (starting from `base` where `n=0`). Such that the result values can be concatenated.

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**
example:

```
case class X(id:Int, value:Int)
val base = spark.createDataset(Seq(X(1, 1), X(2, 2), X(3, 3), X(4, 4), X(5, 5))).toDF

def toA = (x: DataFrame) => x.filter('value.mod(2) === 1).withColumn("value", lit("a"))
def toB = (x: DataFrame) => x.withColumn("value", lit("b"))

val a = toA(base)
val remainder = base.join(a, Seq("id"), "leftanti")
val b = toB(remainder)

a.union(b)

+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|    a|
|  3|    a|
|  5|    a|
|  2|    b|
|  4|    b|
+---+-----+
```

This should work for an arbitrary number of functions (e.g. `toA`, `toB` ... `toN`. Where each time the remainder of the previous result is calculated and passed into the next function. In the end a union is applied to all results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Seq` already has a method `scanLeft` that does this out-of-the-box:

```
funcs.scanLeft(base)((acc, f) => f(acc)).tail
```

Make sure to drop the first element of the result of `scanLeft` if you don't want `base` to be included.

---

Using only foldLeft it is possible too:

```
funcs.foldLeft((base, List.empty[A])){ case ((x, list), f) => 
  val res = f(x)
  (res, res :: list) 
}._2.reverse.reduce(_.union(_))
```

Or:

```
funcs.foldLeft((base, Vector.empty[A])){ case ((x, list), f) => 
  val res = f(x)
  (res, list :+ res) 
}._2.reduce(_.union(_))
```

The trick is to accumulate into a `Seq` inside the `fold`.

Example:

```
scala> val base = 7
base: Int = 7

scala> val funcs: List[Int => Int] = List(_ * 2, _ + 3)
funcs: List[Int => Int] = List($$Lambda$1772/1298658703@7d46af18, $$Lambda$1773/107346281@5470fb9b)

scala> funcs.foldLeft((base, Vector.empty[Int])){ case ((x, list), f) => 
     |   val res = f(x)
     |   (res, list :+ res) 
     | }._2
res8: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(14, 17)

scala> .reduce(_ + _)
res9: Int = 31
```

Comment: Your first example was exactly what I needed. Good thinking to accumulate into a list, never figured you could use foldLeft like that. Awesome :).

Answer (score 0):

I've got a simplified solution using normal collections but the same principle applies.

```
val list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val funcs: Seq[Function[List[Int], List[Int]]] = Seq(times2, by2)

funcs.foldLeft(list) { case(collection, func) => func(collection) } foreach println // prints 1 2 3 4 5

def times2(l: List[Int]): List[Int] = l.map(_ * 2)

def by2(l: List[Int]): List[Int] = l.map(_ / 2)
```

This solution does not hold if you want a single reduced value as your final output e.g. single `Int`; therefore this works as:
`F[B] -> F[B] -> F[B]` and not as `F[B] -> F[B] -> B`; though I guess this is what you need.